# In the list of actions done from moderators, change the ID of a destroyed account to a link to the account itself

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, user-accounts

When moderators follow the link to a destroyed account, they see a page explaining why the account was destroyed.

> [image: screenshot]

The log of the actions taken from a moderator, for a destroyed account, reports only the user ID. It could be better if the user ID would be a link to the account page, which shows what the previous screenshot showed.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Heck, just make *every* deleted account name a link to the account for moderators.